# Why is this d3.text request failing?

Tags: javascript, http, text, d3.js, get

I'm stuck with this for hours now. Please help me to spot the mistake!

Why is this `d3.text` request failing? ([link to diff.php](http://q39.qhor.net/cach/diff.php?action=diff))

```
d3.text("http://q39.qhor.net/cach/diff.php?action=diff", function(diff) {
  document.write(diff); // returns 'null'
});
```

While this is working? ([link to ltcProxy.php](http://freya.syari.net/pool/ltcProxy.php?action=diff))

```
d3.text("http://freya.syari.net/pool/ltcProxy.php?action=diff", function(diff) {
  document.write(diff); // returns a number read from input
});
```

I've been reading the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_text) on this back and forth, tried using different input formats (`text/plain`, `text/html`, etc. ...) but I cant get the first snippet to work.

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: In newer versions of D3, the *second* argument to the callback is the data -- i.e. `function(error, diff)`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Nope, but it seems the request is taking too long for the first link and thats why `diff` is `null`. Not sure how to fix it without losing performance...

Comment: The first is quite fast for me (almost instantly).

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, if the file request returns with an error, the data object (`diff`) will be null.  You could have figured it out much faster if you always use the two-argument version of the callback function, and make the first line of your function an error check:

```
d3.text("http://q39.qhor.net/cach/diff.php?action=diff", function(error, diff) {

  if (error) {
      document.write("Error reading file");
      return;
  }

  document.write(diff); // returns 'null'
});
```

The "error" object passed in by d3 isn't very useful beyond checking for its existence -- it's the XMLHTTPRequest function that was used, not the error returned.  The error itself should be logged to your console by the browser.

Why would a file request return with an error even though you can open the file up directly no problem?  Because Javascript is exceedingly polite when using external files: it will only use them if the server includes a header that says they may be used by your webpage.

Specifically, the error message that should be displaying on your console when you try to run that request will be something like

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://q39.qhor.net/cach/diff.php?action=diff. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

In other words, you cannot use someone else's file in your script unless it specifically tells your browser that you have permission to use it.  The proxy server you use in the second example is fetching the file for you, and then passing it on to the browser with the instruction that it may be used by any website in the `http://syari.net` domain.  If I try to use that file name from JS fiddle, however, I still get an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://freya.syari.net/pool/ltcProxy.php?action=diff. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' whitelists only 'http://syari.net'. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is not in the list, and is therefore not allowed access.

More on Access Control and HTTP requests:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS